# Spider Crawling to the very end of a website

Tags: web-crawler, screen-scraping

Say I have a crawler which begins at the root of a website. No robots.txt or sitemaps. Are there any techniques I can use to determine whether or not there any any unique pages left to crawl on the website?

Comment: Just a guess - haven't really experienced with screen-scraping too much yet - but what about the scrollbar? :)

Comment: Unfortunately no - this is per page basis. I want to know when there are no more pages left to scrape on the website. Edited to make a bit more clear!

Comment: **AFAIK:** Without a robots.txt or sitemap you will never be able to properly scrape it dynamically. You'd have to hardcode a scraper for every root.